# Melting/reshaping time series from wide to long while keeping time column

Tags: r

I'm attempting to reshape the AirPassengers dataset on R from wide to long.

```
data(AirPassengers)
melt(AirPassengers)
```

The issue I am encountering is that 'melt' keeps the value of the AirPassengers data but I need the corresponding time information alongside the output of melt(AirPassengers).

What is the best method to reshape time series data while keeping a time column?

Thank you!

Comment: Just so you know, `AirPassengers` does not have dimensions or columns - they are added by the `ts` timeseries printing - compare `print.default(AirPassengers)` and `print(AirPassengers)` - would `cbind(time(AirPassengers), AirPassengers)` be sufficient?

Comment: that's exactly what I was after, thank you! I had a hard time figuring out why dim(AirPassengers) was always returning NULL, the `ts` timeseries format was doing my head in. Much appreciated.